# Xpath returning value from wrong node

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have some trouble with XPath. For some unknown reason the result I get from my expression is the one from another run of the function.

Here's the constructor of my class:

```
Wine(Node ndWine){
    try{
     xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}

    Node ndName = null;

    try{
        ndName = (Node)xpath.evaluate("//name", ndWine, XPathConstants.NODE);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
    if (ndName != null)
        name = ndName.getTextContent();
}
```

And here's the XML:

```
<cellar>
  <wine>
    <name>Jasnières</name>
  </wine>
  <wine>
    <name>Ballet d'Octobre</name>
  </wine>
</cellar>
```

In the calling method I have another xpath expression that breaks down the document to the list of `<wine>` elements. The above code is called for each node.
In the debugger I check that on the second run the `ndWine` node actually contains data from the second node of the document, but the evaluation always returns the `Jasnieres` value instead of `ballet d'octobre`, which I can't understand.

Any idea of the root cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting the XPath expression with `//` makes it an absolute path. Even though you pass in the `<wine>` element it ignores it and starts at the document root. Add a `.` in front to make it a relative path:

```xml
.//name
```

Or better yet, avoid the `//` syntax if you can. It's best to avoid doing a full `descendant-or-self` search if you know exactly where the `<name>` elements will be. If they'll always be directly inside of a `<wine>` element then use this XPath:

```xml
name
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it! I wasn't aware that even if the source of the XPath evaluation is a specific node it will search through the entire document nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
try {                
     expr = xpath.compile("/cellar/wine/name");
     nodeList = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
} catch (XPathExpressionException ignored) {}

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node != null) {
            NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                Node childNode = childNodes.item(j);
                if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    System.out.println(childNode.getNodeValue());
                }
            }
        }
}
```